# how to create proxy code on unity application

Tags: asp.net, unity-game-engine

i live in iran and unity3d for iran is blocked.i need a unity source code for create app than can connect without other vpn app.how can i add proxy to my source code in unity and visual studio? or is there a library of vpn to add at the source code? i'm Beginner please help me completely. thanks

Comment: You need to start with a portion of code you've done. We are here to help, not coding for you.

Comment: start by reading up the source document on proxy specification https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt